# scroll effect / parallax effect on vertical slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

This is the link to my work: http://webfluxsolutions.com/Teavana/

Under What We Believe In section is the vertical slider. 
This is my html:

```
    <div id="slider">
    <div class="sHead">
                    <h2>What we believe in</h2>
                </div>
        <ul class="slideshow">
                <li class="page1">          
                     <div class="slogan">
                        <div class="captionMain">
                            <div class="captionBox">
                                <div class="sTxt">
                                <h2>Inspiring new <br/>frontiers of taste</h2>
                                <p>Year after year, we integrate more than 400 ingredients to uncover new territories in the world of tea. </p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </li>
                <li class="page2"> 
                     <div class="slogan">
                        <div class="captionMain">
                            <div class="captionBox">
                                <div class="sTxt white">
                                <h2 class="white">Brew, taste,<br/>brew and taste again</h2>
                                <p class="white">We take up to 12 months to select the finest crops of tea and botanicals from all around the world. </p>
                                </div>  
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </li>
                <li class="page3">              
                     <div class="slogan">
                        <div class="captionMain">
                            <div class="captionBox">
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <div class="sTxt white">
                                    <h2 class="white">Bold new takes<br/>on artistry</h2>
                                    <p class="white">Combining age-old knowledge and modern techniques, we reimagine tea into a thousand possibilities. </p>
                                </div>  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

at the moment I'm using bxslider but it's not what I want.

```
        $('#slider .slideshow').bxSlider({  
            mode: 'vertical',
            pager:true,
            auto:true,
            autocontrols:false,
            pause:3000 
        });
```

My aim is to have scroll effect on the slides similar to the slides section (1st section) of this site : http://www.hugeinc.com/

A lot of references online are for full page scroll effect but I only want it for just one section.

Comment: Did you already tried to create it? Get the height of the screen, scroll pos the add event listener for scroll. If statement. If it is on the margin of blah blah. smooth scroll to the height of the screen then reverse.

Comment: I played around with the scroll effect with some references I got off the internet - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrWYXd  However not sure how to incorporate it into my website and the slider I have at the moment. Also it seems like it's quite jittery too

Comment: Check GSAP tweenmax. Best performance library so far. You already got the solution. You need GSAP tweenmax and GSAP scrollTo plugin. And you can also change the other effects into tweenmax so the user can have 60fps on your website.

Comment: The one that I have is on section tag. Would it be the same if I applied it on li items?

Comment: Ofcourse. Javascript can do complex things. Depends on how you program it.